# Page load events in MVC and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

is there a way to do some activity while a webpage is loading?
What I am trying to find out is, in a very simplest way, to show an image or a message like 'Loading ...' when the page starts to load and then hide it or make it dissappear once the page loading finishes.
The user can the continue with the interaction on the page.

I have read and tried the jQuery way of using document.ready but that gets executed once the document is loaded completely. The same is with the load method.

So if I have a page that takes some time to load completely, is there a page event that get fired when the page starts to load which I can hook-up and an after event when the page is ready?

I am currently using ASP.NET MVC to create the app, if that helps.

Here's a sample page:

```
<body>
    <div class=".loading">
        <p>
            <img src="http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif" />
            Please Wait
        </p>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.loading').hide();
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is taking the time? Is it the rendering of the page itself (I.E other JS on the page/images) or is it the logic in your controllers etc?

Comment: If the page takes a long time to load you should be looking at trying to make it load faster.  For example if you are using Linq queries to return data you need to optimise them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start the page with the load message visible and hide it on load `event`. Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="loading">loading....</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.loading').hide(); // hide message when finished with load
});
```

**EDIT**

I've replaced `document.ready` by `windows.load` as document ready doesn't wait images to load.

Comment: Added a div with a loader gif right after the opening body tag, added a img tag with the url of a 2 mb image at Wikipedia. The loader shows while the image downloads but the hide function does not work even with document.ready. Any clues.

Comment: @Codehelp: I had a typo on my code, replace `class=".loading"` by `class="loading"`

Comment: @Codehelp: I've also replaced `document.ready` by `windows.load` after seeing your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a delay on the server, then no there's no event that will allow you to hook into. The only option would be to load your page via ajax then display your loading message on `ajaxStart` and hide it on `ajaxStop`.

If you're talking about a delay on the client however, then the approach Claudio outlined is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.any_div').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the delay is happening.  If it's happening on the server after the user clicks a button, one solution I've used in the past is to display a loading message immediately after the user attempts navigates to the page, before the request is sent to the server.

```
$('a.btn').on('click', function () { 
        $("div.page").showLoading();
    });
```

I'm using the jquery showLoading plugin in the example above, and it's displaying on the button click which causes the browser to show the loading icon while the server is doing its thing.